# JPA @ManyToOne with different datatypes

Tags: jpa, sqldatatypes, many-to-one

I have two old database tables, that i need to use with JPA.

```
TOUR                        VEHICLE
-----------------------     ---------------------
Id NUMBER(10)               VehicleNumber CHAR(3)
VehicleNumber NUMBER(3)     LicensePlate CHAR(10)
```

In my JPA entities I want tu use a @ManyToOne relationship from TOUR to VEHICLE.

Vehicle Entity:

```
public class Vehicle {
  @Id
  @Column(length=3)
  private String VehicleNumber;
...
```

Tour Entity:

```
public class Tour {
  @Id
  @Column(precision=3)
  private BigDecimal Id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="VehicleNumber", referencedColumn="VehicleNumber")
  private Vehicle vehicle;
...
```

But this of course doesn't work since the one vehicle number is translatet to String and the other is translatet to a BigDecimal(precision=3).

So what can i do to join them? Non-numeric values should be ignored.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What do you mean, 'doesn't work?'

Comment: What JPA version are you using?

Comment: I'm using OpenJPA 2.0, which comes with IBM WebSphere Application Server 8.5 and I'm trying to access an IBM DB2/400 on IBM i 7.1. Some of the tables are 20 years and older and I can't do anything to change them without touching various old RPG programms.

Comment: ERROR: <openjpa-2.2.3-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1564471 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "model.Tour.vehicle" declares a column that is not compatible with the expected type "varchar".

Answer (score 0):

`VehicleNumber` in `TOUR` table is a number while in the other one is `CHAR`.
 First you need to match the types (better not to try to hack the standards).

then for `@Id` put the column name not `@Column(precision=3)`. so it should be:

```
public class Tour {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "Id")
  private BigDecimal id;
  ...
}
```

and do the same for the other table.
Oh by the way, I suggest you to use `Long` for the Primary Key not `BigDecimal` unless you have to.
But for entities, you are ok to work with `Long`